# ARM-GAS: how to load address of static array defined in some c-file (PIC and regular code)

Tags: arm, gnu-assembler

I have some simple static array defined in c-file (**const int data_input[1024];**)and I need to access it from my assembly code. What's the right way to do it?

So far, I've been doing it this way:

```
.global data_input

data_input_ptr:
    .word data_input

my_function:
    adr r1, data_input_ptr
    bx lr
```

AFAIK, adr is pseudo-op stands to ldr r1, =data_input_ptr or something like that.

To me the way I do it seems not to be very correct: first of all that adr r1, data_input might potentially use pc relative addressing directly if it detected at link time that it's possible.
Another issue is about PIC: what if the code has to be position independent. How then does it work if value of data_input_ptr has to be initialized by the loader (am I correct about that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it should work, but another way of handling it would be to use the address of the array as a second argument to the assembly function. Something like this:

```
Call from c-file:
my_function(original_argument, data_input);

my_function.h:
void my_function(void *original_argument, int *array_address);

my_function.S:
my_function:
    /* r1 already contains data_input_ptr since second argument ends up in r1 */
    bx lr
```

Comment: I actually did it that way because I had issues with  
 - c++ mangling (I had to make symbols extern "C")  
 - static arrays would have to re-declared to be non-static etc.  
  
So, it seems that it's best to delegate all that dirty work to compiler and pass extra parameter that contains pointers to static arrays etc.